# Format inline result of bashful

Tags: shell-escape, bashful

I discovered the package [`bashful`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/bashful) to print result of a shell command inside the document.
We can print the result in the current line (without carriage return) using the command `\bashStdout`. Here is an example that should write the date of compilation.
For example, I try to insert the date in the document with :

```latex
\bash
date +"%b %d %Y"
\END

Compilation of this document completed on \bashStdout
```

The problem is that in the generated pdf, the result is :

```
    Compilation of this document completed on Jul_15_2021
```

with a special character instead of spaces (replaced here with a `_`).
I saw in the documentation that it is possible to customize the display of the result using `lstdefinestyle` but this command seems to be working only when I use the option `[stdout]` to the command `\bash`.

But with this option, the code

```latex
Compilation of this document completed on 
\bash[stdout]
date +"%b %d %Y"
\END
```

will print

```
    Compilation of this document completed on
Jul 15 2021
```

on many lines

Is there a way to customize the way `bashStdout` is displayed ? I didn't find it in the doc.

Here is the full ECM :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bashful}

\begin{document}

\bash
date +"%b %d %Y"
\END

Compilation of this document completed on \bashStdout

Compilation of this document completed on 
\bash[stdout]
date +"%b %d %Y"
\END

\end{document}
```

Is there a way to solve my issue ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bashful}

\begin{document}

\bash
date +"%b %d %Y"
\END

Compilation of this document completed on \scantokens\expandafter{\bashStdout}

Compilation of this document completed on 
\bash[stdout]
date +"%b %d %Y"
\END

\end{document}
```

or more simply without using any package in this case:

```
\documentclass{article}


\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\let\%\@percentchar
\makeatother

Compilation of this document completed on \input{|date +'\%b \%d \%Y'}.

Compilation of this document completed on 

\input{|date +'\%b \%d \%Y' }.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks ! it works well :)